# Trying to get all the roles in asp.net application but getting error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2, asp.net-roles

I have this code

[image]

As you can see Roles is highlighted and that is what is causing the problem. The error says

> 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.RoleManager'
>   does not contain a definition for 'Roles' and no extension method
>   'Roles' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.RoleManager'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

It is saying are you missing reference or assembly? I am new to identity. I don't know what could be the problem. My header files seem to be fine

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using WebSite2;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to that of identity-1 vs identity-2. The code I was running was for identity v2 but I was working with identity v1 (Visual Studio 2013) and hence the error. Switching to identity v1 fixes the problem. The correct code for v1 is

var context = new ApplicationDbContext();

```
var allRoles = context.Roles.ToList();
ListView1.DataSource = allRoles;
ListView1.DataBind();
```

which fixes the problem. Relevent question
[Getting All Users and All Roles through asp.net Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21505592/getting-all-users-and-all-roles-through-asp-net-identity)